# Image.FromStream Changes the size when the computer change

Tags: .net, image, bitmap

i'm using this code to get a picture and save , the problem is when i tried the application on my virtual machine the count of the array that contains the picture is the same , but the saved picture has different size from the one on the real machine
i tried it on two virtual machine , and the same , it changes on each one

```
    Dim oo = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")

    Dim img1 = oo(0)

    Try

        Dim o1=Gecko.Utils.SaveImageElement.ConvertGeckoImageElementToPng(web, img1, 0.0F, 0.0F, img1.ClientWidth, img1.ClientHeight)

        Dim bitmap As Byte() = o1

        File.WriteAllText("size.txt", o1.Count) 'this stay the same

        Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(bitmap)).save("pic.jpg") 'this is what changes

        Return Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(bitmap))

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

i want to have a saved picture with the same size on every computer
'i used the same net framework version on all of tested machines'

Comment: The most obvious explanation is that ConvertGeckoImageElementToPng() simply produces a different size image.  Browsers don't render content at a predictable size, it is going to depend on the video DPI and zoom preferences.

Comment: I checked the preferences , and it's the same, i did a test in order to know the size of array returned by ConvertGeckoImageElementToPng and it's has the same length